# Change order for sub-menu on page.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

On the page.php from my template i got the follwing code for a sub-menu.

```
$parent = wp_get_post_parent_id($post->ID);

    $args = array(
        'post_parent' => $parent,
        'post_type'   => 'page', 
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );

    if($parent){
        foreach(get_children($args) as $child){
            echo '<li data-slug="'.$child->post_name.'"><a href="'.$child->guid.'">'.$child->post_title.'</a></li>'; 
        }
    }
```

Now i want for a specific page a different approach.

I have 4 pages with the ID's 131, 119, 63 and 59.

In the above way, the will ordered  in 59, 63, 119, 131.

I want them ordered into 63, 59, 131, 119

How can i do that without change the other page-submenus?

Thank for your help :)

Comment: Check this `plugin`. https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-page-ordering/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
$args = array(
        'post_parent' => $parent,
        'post_type'   => 'page', 
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'orderby' => 'post__in',
        'post__in' => array(63, 59, 131, 119),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => $parent,
    'post_type'   => 'page', 
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'post__in'       => [63, 59, 131, 119],
    'orderby'        => 'post__in',
);
```